# Setting Tooltips for Items / Controls in a UserControl

Tags: vb.net, winforms, inheritance, user-controls, .net-8.0

I try to set the tooltip for a custom `UserControl` I created.

The `UserControl` contains a single text box and surrounding canvas area. The reason behind doing this is to enable an illusion of a vertically centered `TextBox` with attached label. The label is being created via `TextRenderer.DrawText`, so the Tooltip works when hovering over the heading text as I am really hovering over the `UserControl` canvas in that case.

When being rendered, it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

As expected, the tooltip (which is assigned on the containing form) only displays when the mouse pointer is over the UserControl and not when over the TextBox in the UserControl.

[image]

This is the designer generated code of the containing form:

```
' 
' usrCtrlTxtBox
' 
usrCtrlTxtBox.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
usrCtrlTxtBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
resources.ApplyResources(usrCtrlTxtBox, "usrCtrlTxtBox")
usrCtrlTxtBox.Name = "usrCtrlTxtBox"
ToolTip1.SetToolTip(usrCtrlTxtBox, resources.GetString("usrCtrlTxtBox.ToolTip"))
```

I now want to assign the same tooltip text to the contained TextBox inside the user control. For this I somehow need to access the tooltip set for the `UserControl` itself. After browsing through the .Net source code I discovered that the Tooltip1.SetTooltip command finally calls a method called `SetToolTipToControl` (lines 1280 to 1286 in Tooltip.cs) which ultimately calls this method (lines 10941 to 10944 in Control.cs):

```
internal virtual void SetToolTip(ToolTip toolTip)
{
    // Control doesn't have a specific logic after a toolTip is set
}
```

So I thought it would be a good idea to override this method with a custom Sub in my `UserControl`:

```
Protected Overrides Sub SetToolTip(outerTooltip As ToolTip)
    ToolTipInner.SetToolTip(txtBox, outerTooltip.GetToolTip(Me))
    'txtBox is the inner TextBox of the UserControl
    'TooltipInner is a ToolTip-Control inside the UserControl
End Sub
```

Sadly this doesn't work as planned as the compiler complains about:

```
BC31417
'Protected Overrides Sub SetToolTip(outerTooltip As ToolTip)' cannot override 'Friend Overridable Overloads Sub SetToolTip(toolTip As ToolTip)' because it is not accessible in this context.
```

I am not very familiar with C# but I thought I would be able to override internal virtual methods as `UserControl` ultimately inherits from `Control` if I am not mistaken. I am out of ideas here and would appreciate any help. Any possibilty to access the UserControls tooltip from inside the Control itself?

**Edit / addition:**

As the UserControl will be used on many different forms with many different possible headings and tooltip texts, these strings aren't static but are being set by the containing form of the UserControl. Due to the need to translate these texts, I use RESX files for each of the forms, where the text being set to each instance of the UserControl is being translated during the InitializeComponent phase of the form.

**Summary:**

I try overriding the `SetToolTip` method from inside my `UserControl` to access the outer tooltip of the user control. I want to avoid constructs like `Reflection` and Shenanigans like `Me.FindForm().Controls.Find("ToolTip1")`.

Comment: Not exactly clear what you're after. Why don't you add a ToolTip to the UserControl directly? Does it need to be a ToolTip child of a Form? -- That method is `internal virtual`, not `protected internal virtual`, you cannot override it directly. You *could* add your own method, then call it from a custom ToolTip Component, for example. But, as mentioned, it's not exactly clear (to me, at least) why you're trying to do this

Comment: As the UserControl will be used on many different forms with many different possible headings and tooltip texts, these strings aren't static but are being set by the containing form of the UserControl. Due to the need to translate these texts, I use RESX files for each of the forms, where the text being set to each instance of the UserControl is being translated during the InitializeComponent phase of the form. I am not sure if this is feasible by using a ToolTip control inside the UserControl only.

The idea with a custom ToolTip component sounds interesting. I will give it a thought. Thx!

Comment: All right. You should add these details to the question -- Note that when a Control shows an assigned ToolTip, you get a `WM_NOTIFY` message in the Window's Procedure (i.e. in the UC's `WndProc`, in your case). The ToolTip's Handle (the Handle of the underlying NativeWindow) is specified in the `hwndFrom` member of the [NMHDR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/richedit/ns-richedit-nmhdr) struct you get from LPARAM (`(NMHDR?)m.GetLParam(typeof(NMHDR);`)

Comment: The `code` member specifies the state (ToolTip Popup; First Time, just once - IIRC ; ToolTip Close <- I don't remember which are the values, but it's easy enough to verify) -- As a note, you have tagged the question `.net`, which refers to .NET Framework, but the C# code you have mentioned relates to .NET 6+ only

Comment: I managed to create a solution by using a custom tooltip component which just inherits the normal tooltip component and overloads the Sub SetToolTip(Control, String). I will post it here so other people searching for it may find it. Thanks for giving me a nudge into the right direction. I will give your other ideas regarding WndProc a try. Maybe there is a possibility without using an inherited custom ToolTip component.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

Create the following `Sub` inside your `UserControl`:

```
Friend Sub SetToolTipInnerControls(caption As String)
    ToolTipInner.SetToolTip(txtBox, caption)
    ' Add all inner controls you want to have the same tooltip or loop through the Controls collection.
End Sub
```

Create a custom component, inheriting the built-in `ToolTip` component:

```
Namespace Controls
    Public Class ToolTip
        Inherits System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip

        Public Overloads Sub SetToolTip(ctrl As Control, caption As String)
            MyBase.SetToolTip(ctrl, caption)

            If TypeOf ctrl Is CtrlTxtBox Then
                DirectCast(ctrl, CtrlTxtBox).SetToolTipInnerControls(caption)
            End If
            ' If you have multiple different UserControls which need this behavior, you could also check against the common type they derive from.
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Use this custom `ToolTip` on your forms instead of the regular `ToolTip` component.

The designer will create the usual code for you when assigning tooltips to your controls:

```
ToolTipOnForm.SetToolTip(usrCtrlTxtBox, resources.GetString("usrCtrlTxtBox.ToolTip"))
```

This will call the overridden `Sub` which then will call the `Sub` on your `UserControl`.